# Passing a parameter from JavaScript to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to pass a string value to a create item dialog, and am not sure on how to do it.

This is the code in my view:

**JavaScript:**

```
function newRoute() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create")',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "success") //successfully created the new route
                window.location.href = '@Url.RouteUrl(ViewContext.RouteData.Values)'
            else
                $.facybox(data); // there are validation errors, show the dialog w/ the errors
        }
    });
}
```

**View:**

```
<td>@route</td>
<td>
    <a href="javascript:newRoute();" class="button">Add</a>
</td>
```

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Create(string routeName = "")
    {
        PopulateRouteInfoViewBag();

        var newRoute = new RouteInformation();

        newRoute.Name = routeName;

        return View(newRoute);
    }
```

I'm trying to take the value in @route and pass it over to the Create controller to have my dialog pop up with the passed in string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ActionLink html helper method and pass the route variable like this.

```
@{
   string route="somevaluehere";
 }
@Html.ActionLink("Add","Create","YourControllerName",
                          new { routeName=route},new {@id="addLnk"})
```

Now handle the click event

```
$(function(){

   $("#addLnk").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();  //prevent normal link click behaviour
     var _this=$(this); 

      //do your ajax call now
      $.ajax({
        url: _this.attr("href"),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "success") //successfully created the new route
                window.location.href = 'someValidUrlHere'
            else
                $.facybox(data); 
         }
       });

   });     

});
```

Also, You may consider building the path to the new page(action method) and return that as part of your JSON result and let the client read it from the JSON.

instead of appending the route variable value to the querystring, you may consider it as the part of message body.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.  1, use `Url.Action("controllerName", "actionName", new {routeName = "your route name here"})` or 2, use the data property of the object passed into $.ajax.

For 2 your javascript would look something like

```
function newRoute() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create")',
        data: {
            route: "your data here"
        }
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "success") //successfully created the new route
                window.location.href = '@Url.RouteUrl(ViewContext.RouteData.Values)'
            else
                $.facybox(data); // there are validation errors, show the dialog w/ the errors
        }
    });
}
```